# Department not allowing me to take courses from another department even though everyone else is allowed

Tags: graduate-school, administration

I am a graduate student here. There are two set of rules applying to the degree I am seeking:

- rules from the university
- rules from my department

Using the above sets of rules, you have to make a plan of study (POS) which would be the list of coursework you complete towards your degree.

I followed all those rules, but a few days ago the administrative assistant who’s in charge of all this suddenly said that I was not allowed to take courses from a certain department.

I asked them for the reason for this and got varying responses which included:

1. The university office raised an objection.
2. The department in question raised an objection.
3. There was some new rule which has been in power since last year.

   (I found this hard to believe because as long as you follow the university and department rules to the letter, which I did, you're basically allowed to take whatever courses you want to fill in your additional requirements.)

After some digging in, it turns out there’s no such rule. In fact many people from my department have taken courses from that certain department this semester.

What should I do? I feel like I’m being singled out here. I feel this is also unfair if I’m the only one who’s forced to follow this non-existing rule.

This just happened:

I kept asking them about it and the reason for all this changed to the CSCI department again.

They denied singling me out, this was a lie, due to the reason highlighted below.

Finally, I revealed how other students in the my dept are also taking these courses and how people typically busy with research would only do so  for courses which they can use towards their degree (so they were not taking them to fill in credits only).

In the end, get this, this person tells me that the whole ordeal was just a 'mistake' which also suggests that this would have gone unnoticed if I hadn't asked.

Comment: This is an issue for you to take with your department chair (and possibly up the line to your graduate dean.)  It's really not possible to answer this question without specific knowledge of the rules of your institution.

Comment: Any idea why they would do this? Who do you think would have power to make the administrative assistant write this nonsense?

Comment: My point is that I can't answer the question because I'm not familiar with the institution or its specific rules.  You haven't provided enough context, and even if you did provide information about your degree program requirements, university requirements for the graduate degree, and the courses that you want to take, I couldn't determine whether or not such a rule had recently been added.

Comment: At my institution, for example, my graduate advisees can't take any course without my approval.  I could clearly prevent you from taking a course from the department in question.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it is my advisor who did this? If he did, then he's being highly covert about this, since he basically said he knew nothing when I asked him about all of this

Comment: I'm not suggesting that at all, just giving you an example of a rule (at my institution) which might prevent a student from taking a course that he/she wants to take.

Comment: Is the course you want to take from the other department relevant for your degree? Or are you taking it for fun?

Comment: Sounds like you're having a stressful situation.  Still, it'd seem best to avoid the rant stuff at the end of the question.

Comment: @Nick S, You don't take courses for fun, sadly it's not like that. Each course is challenging and worthwhile in it's own way (point is to learn something), I guess being a student (hope you are too), I guess it's one of the sole reasons at the university right? Say for example, there are people who don't see the point in someone working on their education, then it seems like they don't carry the spirit of academica and should not be there at all, right? If all they do is try to push people out, then they must really be struggling with their own shit, I feel sad for them.

Comment: I get that you're upset, but this is a Q&A site where we aim to compile a library of high quality questions and answers, not a "Here's my story, my department sucks amirite" site. We try to keep questions focused on the actual question, professional in tone, and in a form where they'll be most useful to other readers in the future.

Comment: I added in the end result for future reference (and how I came to that conclusion)

Comment: @ff524 I never said that my 'department sucks' but what this one person did was wrong (at behest of whomsoever they did so)

Comment: @pong In theory you are right, but in practice I know students who took or tried to take courses from other departments because that particular course was labeled as easy or the the instructor was known to be more lenient. And yes some students are trying to learn, but sadly there are lots and lots of students taking a class only because it is mandatory for their degree, and they are going to class just to get a (passing) grade. And I met students which only went to University because their parents forced them. So, no, it is not always true that students take classes because they want to learn

Comment: @Nick S I see all the points you're listing out (although majorly branched out through your imagination, maybe a bit too much)a, but none of them validates as marking the student as doing something wrong. In an academic sense, they're a student, so say for example, mobbing (or for that matter any form of unnecessary 'fix' on anyone) any student for being a student would count as harassment (probably maybe even a unlawful if you want to be a part of it). Nor can I understand how this helps the argument how all courses are courses in their own right, but whatever

Comment: Also important to mention, if the rules all line up, like anything in life, it's not really anybody's business what someone else might be doing (I mean gossip may be spicy, but after a point there's that point which is typically why laws exist, i.e., animalistic instincts don't overpower human nature ). Many countries have privacy laws protecting people's information, many don't. To each their own, but the crux of the matter is that people do their own thing and one keeps to oneself. I mean, that is how it usually goes, unless someone else may have some other abnormality in mind.

Comment: @pong The sad part is that I met students which took courses from other departments just because they thought they were "fluffy". I wish students like this would be only part of my imagination, but in reality people are not perfect. While many students are going to University to learn, the reality is that in some situations the GPA can become more important than the learning itself: the students could lose his/her scolarship because of the GPA, and in some cases they cannot afford school anymore, or the student could be on probabion and be thrown out if they don\t get a certain grade.

Comment: My comment typically doesn't apply to strong students, and I agree strong students would most of the time not do such things. But it only takes some weak students doing this for a rule, even if sometimes unwritten, to be added, and then the rule affects everyone.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be good at looking up university policy and rules, and reading them carefully.  So I suggest your next step would be to look up procedures for appealing academic decisions.  Also, get to know your university hierarchy.

Universities vary in how decision making is done, so it’s impossible for me to be more specific about *your* university.

But I will give you a trick that I’ve had good success with in a variety of educational institutions: Phone or visit the secretary of the highest-level dean you can find that sits above your department, and ask his or her advice for where in the hierarchy to bring your problem.  This secretary is often the most competent, knowledgeable person about university hierarchy in the whole institution.

And a general tip: Tell your story concisely and with a neutral tone of voice.  Begin by stating the problem.  Initially, leave out the numbered list of crazy reasons you were given (but be prepared to provide them if they ask you why the department rejected your proposal).